# Odata pulling different times?

Tags: odata, acumatica

When I pull data using ODATA in excel I get time with -3hrs compared to the one in the instance.
Is there a way I can get the exact time as the one on the instance?
[Comaparison of instance time and Excel time pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zT9Lg.png)

I tried to check the server time to make sure its the same as the one on the instance. My SQL server
is in UTC. could this be the reason why? It seems ODATA might be fetching data directly from the database through the generic inquiry.

Comment: Please show an example of the actual output JSON and tag the post with the specific version of OData. If this is v4, then the time zone will be specified or the UTC format will be used. There should be no ambiguity about this from a data perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that the records were saved in the wrong timezone (server or SQL)
In the GI take the column that is wrong and add this:
=DateAdd(today(),’h’, 3)
Replace 'today()' with your needed field, now the data will display as you want them